# Flow Formula Editor: Syntax Error for simple IF statement

Tags: formula

I received the following error creating a formula within the Visual Flow formula editor after selecting he 'Check Syntax' button. Output should be a Date/Time value:

> The formula expression is invalid: Syntax error. Missing ')'

For the following statement:

```
IF(
    {!$Record.Date_Time_Field_1__c} < 14:00:00, 
    {!$Record.Date_Time_Field_1__c} + 04:00:00, 
    {!$Record.Date_Time_Field_2__c}
)
```

This seems fairly straightforward so I am hoping someone can shed some light. Am I missing something related to the Visual Flow formula editor, $Record placeholders or Date/Time values here that results in the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error here is misleading

The actual issue is that the datetime comparison and addition is incorrect.

It seems to me that for the "condition" part of your `IF()`, you simply want to see if the time portion of the datetime is before 14:00. Setting aside concerns about handling time zones, you want to use the `TIMEVALUE()` function. You also need to use `TIMEVALUE()` for your literal `14:00:00` (and it needs to be enclosed in single or double quotes)

`TIMEVALUE({!$Record.Date_Time_Field_1__c}) < TIMEVALUE("14:00:00")`

We don't use `hh:mm:ss` format in datetime addition. Instead, you add a "decimal" type number. Whole numbers are the number of days, and the fractional part represents partial days. To add 4 hours, you want...

`{!$Record.Date_Time_Field_1__c} + (4.0/24.0)` (or `+ 1.0/6.0`, or roughly `+ 0.16666667`)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is comparision with right data type.

```
IF(
    {!$Record.Date_Time_Field_1__c} < DATETIMEVALUE("2005-11-15 17:00:00") , 
    {!$Record.Date_Time_Field_1__c} + 4, 
    {!$Record.Date_Time_Field_2__c}
)
```

In the if condition, you have to compare with datetimevalue data type. If you want to add, you can add number to datetime field.

**Update**

To add hours, we can use this:-

Add N hours to a date/time field: Datetimefield__c + (N/24)
In these, N is the number of hours

```
IF(
    {!$Record.Date_Time_Field_1__c} < DATETIMEVALUE("2005-11-15 17:00:00") , 
    {!$Record.Date_Time_Field_1__c} + (4/24), 
    {!$Record.Date_Time_Field_2__c}
)
```

Comment: datetime + 4 would add 4 days rather than 4 hours

Comment: Are you sure that `4/24` would return a decimal instead of doing integer division and returning 0?

Comment: Thanks @DerekF, I have added the hour version as well

Comment: @DerekF 4/24 worked fine for me. I don't see any issue.